# Where does iterator() belong to?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, iterator

When we create a reference for the interface, `Iterator`,

```
Iterator itr = arraylist.iterator();
```

Is that `iterator()` function a method of `ArrayList` class or the `Iterator` interface?

Comment: you can see yourself ;) in ArrayList.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList<E>` implements `List<E>` which extends `Collection<E>` which extends `Iterable<E>`.

Therefore `ArrayList` has to implement the `iterator()` method because it indirectly implements `Iterable`, where it is declared. The implementation of the method is by `ArrayList` itself.

Answer (score 3):

It is a method declared in `Iterable` and implemented in `ArrayList`. It returns an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator over a collection. Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework.

- It avoids ConcurrentModificationException
- Iterator has a remove method using which we can delete elements from the underlying object.
- It removes the last element returned by the iterator.

Reference [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-iterator/)